# Returning the SUM of offers in main category

Tags: php, sql, count, sum, mariadb

Im struggling with returning the sum of offers from specific main category(main category is one which doesn't have parent_id. Main category include many subcategories).

**Category table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
    `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` int,
    `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL unique,
    `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `active` boolean NOT NULL default 1
);
```

**Offer table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `offer` (
    `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int NOT NULL,
    `category_id` int NOT NULL,
    `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL unique,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    `budget` int NOT NULL,
    `remote` boolean NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(255),

    `pub_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `exp_date` datetime NOT NULL,

    `sent_at` datetime NOT NULL,


    `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `active` boolean NOT NULL default 1
);
```

This query returns all subcategories with offer count from that subcategory. What i want to accomplish is that it will be also a column like 'parent_offers' where will be value of all offers in all subcategories from specified main category

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.slug, parent.name AS `parent_name`, parent.id AS `parent_id`, parent.slug as 'parent_slug', COUNT(o.id) as cat_offers
FROM category AS c
JOIN category AS parent ON parent.id = c.parent_id
LEFT JOIN offer o ON c.id = o.category_id
WHERE c.active = true
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY parent.name, c.name ASC
```

**Graphic example of what im trying to accomplish:**

```
|---------------------|--------------|-----------------|--------------|
|      parent_cat     |   category   | cat_offers      | parent_offers|
|---------------------|--------------|-----------------|--------------|
|          10         |      31      |      7          |       16     |
|---------------------|--------------|-----------------|--------------|
|          10         |      32      |      2          |       16     |
|---------------------|--------------|-----------------|--------------| 
|          10         |      33      |      6          |       16     |
|---------------------|--------------|-----------------|--------------| 
|          10         |      34      |      1          |       16     |
|---------------------|--------------|-----------------|--------------|
```

Already tried with joining second time offer table with other conditions, trying to do different subselects and nothing worker for me. Feel like im going round and round.

Comment: @Akina, sorry did a mistake in tagging - its a Mariadb(10.0.27-MariaDB).

Exactly, parent-child scheme is strictly 2levels

Comment: 1) Add all this info into the question text, it is not visible as a comment. 2) Add some sample data as INSERT INTO script, and desired answer for this data. You may simplify the structures and remove excess columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need do a subquery.
Ex.:

```
    SELECT c.id, c.name, c.slug, parent.name AS `parent_name`, 
parent.id AS `parent_id`, parent.slug as 'parent_slug', 
    (SELECT COUNT(o.*) FROM offer o WHERE c.id = o.category_id) as cat_offers
        FROM category AS c
        JOIN category AS parent ON parent.id = c.parent_id
        WHERE c.active = true
        GROUP BY c.id
        ORDER BY parent.name, c.name ASC
```